# Plotting works, but manipulating the plot does not

Tags: plotting

If the following works for me,

```
Block[{a = 0.35, b = 0.25}, Plot[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]A, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 50}}, Filling -> Axis]]
```

then why won't this manipulate work:

```
Manipulate[Plot[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]A, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 50}}, Filling -> Axis], {{a, 1/2}, 0, 1}, {{b, 1/2}, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Make your plotting function a function of a and b

Comment: I am quite new to Mathematica. @Lotus, could you demonstrate, please?

Comment: How is \[ScriptCapitalD]A defined ? Give me its definition.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer because the question is incomplete. Here is an example though:

If you are plotting a GammaDistribution with two parameters we can define

```
\[ScriptCapitalD]A[a_, b_] := GammaDistribution[a, b];
```

Now:

```
Block[{a = 0.35, b = 0.25}, 
 Plot[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]A[a, b], x], {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 50}}, Filling -> Axis]]

Manipulate[
 Plot[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]A[a, b], x], {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 50}}, Filling -> Axis], {{a, 1/2}, 0, 
  1}, {{b, 1/2}, 0, 1}]
```